# How to apply styles to .rss files or Atom feed files

Tags: php, xslt, rss, feed, atom-feed

I created an atom feed for my website.

`test.rss` is my file. I also created a `test.xsl` file for my feed. But it's not working.

If I change `test.rss` to `test.xml` then it works. Is there is any option to apply styles to Atom feed with a `.rss` extenstion.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser?

Comment: I assume from the sound of it that you're trying to do the styling in the browser using an <?xml-stylesheet> directive. Check the Content-Type: header returned by your server for the .rss file . It is probably NOT "text/xml" .  You may need to configure your server so it sends the correct content type to identify .rss files as xml.

Comment: Also: if it's an atom file, why are you calling it ".rss"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .htaccess file to associate `.rss` with `text/xml`:

```
AddType text/xml .rss
```

**References**

- [httpd modules, mode_mime: AddType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)